# Pycharm IDE issue/problem on pygame module

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

Pygame does not work in Pycharm despite everything works at python IDLE.
It says:

AttributeError: module 'pygame' has no attribute 'init'

Comment: That error is showing when you run your code or is it an error that pycharm displays inside the editor as Nenri is suspecting?

Comment: Could you give a short example of what you the code you have used and give some insight when exactly you are seeing the above mentioned error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the given information is not enough for properly answering this question, I can tell you a one cause for this error from my personal experience.

Most probably you have named your source file as `pygame.py` or you have a directory named pygame somewhere in your path.